# Spring cloud stream errors channel not working

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream

### EDIT:

Use Case: receive request, process them and notify someone when the request finished. Put in another queue when the process has an error to reprocess later.

I need an API which receives a payload and sends it to a queue (jobs to be processed). Then pickup the messages and start using that payload to invoke another rest service, and queue the response of that call into a new queue (jobs done) which then another service will pick that messages and notify another service about it's completion.

So API POST stores in a queue, pick up the message process it, store the result of that process in another queue.

---

I have an application with two bindings, one for idle jobs and one for processed jobs. The application work as intended, but when I throw an exception, after spring tries to reprocess the message 3 times, it's not sending a message to processed.default.errors, instead it throws an exception:

> Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: failed to send Message to channel 'processed.default.errors'; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Retry Policy Exhausted

```
@Component
public interface JobBinding {

    String INPUT = "jobs-in";
    String OUTPUT = "jobs-out";

    @Input(INPUT)
    SubscribableChannel input();

    @Output(OUTPUT)
    MessageChannel output();
}
```

-

```
@Component
public interface ProcessedBinding {

    String INPUT = "processed-in";
    String OUTPUT = "processed-out";

    @Input(INPUT)
    SubscribableChannel input();

    @Output(OUTPUT)
    MessageChannel output();
}
```

I enable both of them:

```
@EnableBinding({JobBinding.class, ProcessedBinding.class})
public class BindingsConfiguration {
}
```

Then i process the job:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class JobProcessor {

    @StreamListener(JobBinding.INPUT)
    @SendTo(ProcessedBinding.OUTPUT)
    public Message<Job> handleJob(@Payload Job job) {
        log.info("Processing {}", job);
        job.addMetadata("status", "processed");
        return MessageBuilder.withPayload(job).build();
    }
}
```

And then I k-boom:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class DoneProcessor {

    @StreamListener(ProcessedBinding.INPUT)
    public void handleJob(@Payload Job job) {
        log.info("Notifying {}", job);
        throw new RuntimeException("puff");
    }
}
```

My application.properties looks like:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.jobs-out.destination=jobs
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.jobs-in.destination=jobs
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.jobs-in.group=default

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.processed-out.destination=processed
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.processed-in.destination=processed
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.processed-in.group=default

spring.cloud.stream.default.contentType=application/json
```

I tried reading the docs of spring stream cloud by I couldn't find a solution. The queue should be created automatically.

Comment: There is a lot going on in your config, so let's try to eliminate some of it for clarity.
First, you don't need `@Component` on any of the components you listed
Second, using `-` in the names can lead to unintended consequences considering `-` is a reserved character in java and even though you are using it in String, keep in mind that it used by us (the framework) for variety of tings. Use `camelCase` instead.

Comment: You also don't need `...default.contentType=application/json`, since it is the actual default

Comment: Also, I am not sure I understand why is your in/out points to the same destination. Perhaps you can explain your use case (not design) as to what do you need to accomplish.

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky i updated my question, thanks for the interest.

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky im thinking maybe my use case is not good for spring cloud stream and i should use spring-rabbitmq for the workers alone as a worker.

Comment: It may very well be the possibility, but without knowing your use case it is impossible to tell